# Can GitHub wikis use wikitext templates?

Tags: github, mediawiki, wikitext

GitHub wiki pages support wiki markup syntax, and when using curly braces (which, in MediaWiki, loads the contents of another page; e.g., `{{Pagename}}` would transclude page "Template:Pagename") they aren't shown in the output page, but instead only output whitespace. Are wiki templates supported in GitHub wikis, do curly braces perform some other function, or do curly braces only output whitespace just to have compatability with MediaWiki?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses Markdown, which does not support templates. You can view the Markdown documentation [here](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/).

Comment: I'm talking about GitHub Wikis, which do support Mediawiki.

Comment: Ah, MediaWiki on github does not support all MediaWiki magic words

Comment: So GitHub wikis only support the markup aspects of MediaWiki, not anything complex?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes that's how that works.